# How would be the tables structure if i want to add multiples csv files to a database?

Tags: sql, database, csv

I have 3 sensors, 3 types of measures and users.
When the sensors save a measure it is written as 1 csv per sensor saving all the data during the 10 minutes measure. So i would get 3 csv per measure, 1 for each sensor like this:

| Timestamp | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5865 | 0.7456 |
| 2 | 0.9652 | 0.8542 |
| . | . | . |

So each user for each measure has 3 csv (1 per sensor) containing several tuples and some columns.

And I've veen trying to look for a way to store that in a database but i don't find how.

Like i can't have a measures table since i have 3 csv per measure?

How could be the tables structure of this scenario?

I was thinking in combining the data from the 3 sensor in one table having the columns of the 3 csv files, but the thin is that this measures are made during 10 minutes, so that tables would have the instances of just 1 measure and i would have to have 1 table per measure?

Comment: First of all, which database is it? Solution depends on that. Then, you said "it is written as 1 CSV per sensor". Written *into what*? A file, so you have number of rows whose values are comma-separated and we then call it a "CSV file"? If so, it can be loaded into a database, into a table that has (at least) 4 columns (one which identifies the sensor, and 3 that contain data you posted). Once again, the way you'd load that into a database depends on database itself. As of Oracle, you'd use SQL*Loader utility or external table; can't tell about other databases.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify if the measurements are independent, or if you wish to combine timestamps so that TS1 has data for all 3 sensors ?  In other words, make your desired output clear.

Comment: @Littlefoot i haven't decide yet which database to use, i was just trying to clarify the tables structure. Yes, for each measure the user makes, i get 3 csv file(1 per sensor). The thing about doing it the way you say is that i would have 1 table for each measure? Since the user can make multiple measures an i have 3 csv files per each measure

Comment: Based on info you shared so far, that would certainly be **only one table** which stores data for all sensors you have. Mind you: tomorrow you'll decide to add two additional sensors. What will you do then? Create two additional tables? Sure, you can do that. But, what about your current queries? There might be any number of them that fetch data in various ways - you'd have to modify **all** of them to include two additional tables. OK, you'll do that as well. But, next month you'll add 5 more sensors ... Shortly: that's not the way to go. Use only one table and a sensor identifier.

Comment: Doing so, you wouldn't have to do ANYTHING with application itself. All queries, forms, reports ... everything will keep working. You'd just add new sensors' data into existing table.

Comment: @MyICQ tbh i didn't have my desired output clear, right know i have and app that you have to choose manually the csv files for the 3 sensor from your file folder, and then some calculation are made. And what i want to do is to have all the measures in a database so that it can be done automatically from the app, but im not sure how to structure those tables

Comment: @Littlefoot yes, i like the idea of having the data from the csv files in the same table (3 sensor in the same table), the thing is that the user can make multiple measures, and that is 3 csv files each one with 10 minutes data of the sensors, so even if i have the 3 sensors in the same table, it would be correct to have the different measures in the same table? Having each of that measures 1 instance per second during 10 minutes?

Comment: You'd use various **columns** to distinguish what is what. SENSOR_ID (to know which sensor sent data), VALUE (e.g. 28 (degrees Celsius), 1013 (pressure in hectopascals), ...), MEASURE_ID (to know what "28" means >> degrees measured in Celsiuses, etc.) and whatever else you might need.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to understand exactly what you're asking, but from what I can see, you want a table that contains columns for:

- MeasurementID
- SensorID
- Timestamp
- Value1
- Value2

Then when you populate this table from your CSV files, you differentiate between the 3 files you get for each measurement using `SensorID`, writing a different value to this field depending on which sensors CSV file the record came from.

`MeasurementId` would be used to differentiate between different measurements made by the same user at different times (if this is not captured by the `Timestamp` field, which is just an integer in your example data in your question. If the combination of `SensorID` and `Timestamp` will always be unique, then you don't need the `MeasurementID` field.

You might also want to include a `User` field to identify the user who took the Measurement(s).